# DataExtension APIProperty how to pass a date or number

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap

I have been through the documentation on updating data extension through soap api which is fine, but no example on how up pass a date or number through. APIProperty only seems to allow strings?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried adding a number column and updating the data? XML is basically string based, so you should be able to just pass in the number.

Comment: Looks like yo can just pass a date and number as a string. Just format the date MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt

Answer (score 1):

Most SOAP libraries will take care of date conversion. Ultimately the date will need to appear as below:

http://help.exacttarget.com/cs-CZ/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/incoming_date_normalization/

Datetime examples can be found in some of the scheduling and event tracking. Here it is formatted with -6 UTC (server time): 2010-05-16T12:32:00-06:00. From:

https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/scheduling_an_email_send_definition/